# Make bash script exit if no user input in stdin

Tags: bash, null, stdin

My bash script is supposed to get user input to deal with a particular file exiting as in:

```
if [ -e "formatted_log.csv" ]
then
    printf "\nPresence of formatted_log.csv file detected: It appears this script has already been run is this dir.\n"
    printf "Appending can cause errors.\n"
    read -e -p "Would you like to continue?[y/n]" stdin
```

This logic checks the user's input:

```
if [ $stdin = "n" ] || [ $stdin = "N" ];
then 
printf "\nOkay, exiting.\n"
exit;
fi
if [ $stdin != "y" ]&&[ $stdin != "Y" ]&&[ $stdin != "n" ]&&[ $stdin != "N" ]; 
then 
printf "\nPlease use a valid input (y/n)...exiting.\n"
exit;
    fi
fi
```

The issue is that if you just press enter the script executes as though a "y" or a "Y" have been input, and I don't know why. My understanding is that the way this is written, it should exit if the user puts in anything other than a y,Y,n,or N.

It prints this when you have no input:

```
master_script.sh: line 14: [: =: unary operator expected
master_script.sh: line 14: [: =: unary operator expected
master_script.sh: line 19: [: !=: unary operator expected
```

But doesn't exit – how can I make it exit?

Comment: Switching to the `[[ ]]` form of [conditional expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) will probably get you there, from a quick look.  Also make sure every `[` `]` `&&` `||` and the like has spaces around it.  [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) can help you.

Comment: There's no point if telling the user they gave an invalid input if you are just going to exit anyway (as if they typed `n` or `N`).

Comment: `test -f` is *not* checking for existence - it's much more picky than that.  You need either to write `-e` or change your description.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you- I didn't even realize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've tagged this with "Bash", you should have the more powerful `[[ ]]` operator at your disposal. You could then simplify to something like this:

```
read stdin

if [[ $stdin == [Nn] ]]; then
    echo "Exiting"
    exit
fi

if [[ $stdin != [YyNn] ]]; then
    echo "Invalid input, exiting"
    exit
fi
```

`==` (or `=`) and `!=` in `[[ ]]` perform *pattern matching*, so you can use patterns to check if your input is valid, in a single expression like `[YyNn]`.

If you want to ask for input until the user enters something valid, you could loop like this:

```
while [[ $stdin != [YyNn] ]]; do
    read -p 'Continue? ' stdin
done
```

Notice that while it's almost always good practice to quote your variables in Bash, you don't have to within `[[ ]]`. And if your pattern is in a variable, it actually *must not* be quoted, or it isn't interpreted as a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hint of using pattern matching!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *NOT* having the quotes around the variable `$stdin` which is not retained with an empty value when quotes are not present,

For example, the `[...]` sees the expressions as below when the variable is empty,

```
+ '[' = n ']'
script.sh: line 9: [: =: unary operator expected
+ '[' = N ']'
script.sh: line 9: [: =: unary operator expected
+ '[' '!=' y ']'
script.sh: line 14: [: !=: unary operator expected
+ '[' 0 eq 0 ']'
```

You need to properly quote them, to make it work, in line

```
9 if [ "$stdin" = "n" ] || [ "$stdin" = "N" ];
```

and

```
14  if [ "$stdin" != "y" ] && [ "$stdin" != "Y" ] && [ "$stdin" != "n" ] && [ "$stdin" != "N" ];
```

with this, the enter key press are safely handled as,

```
+ '[' '' = n ']'
+ '[' '' = N ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' y ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' Y ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' n ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' N ']'
```

with the above changes running the full script and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the prompt, in debugger mode,

```
 bash -x script.sh 
+ '[' -f file ']'
+ printf '\nPresence of formatted_log.csv file detected: It appears this script has already been run is this dir.\n'

Presence of formatted_log.csv file detected: It appears this script has already been run is this dir.
+ printf 'Appending can cause errors.\n'
Appending can cause errors.
+ read -e -p 'Would you like to continue?[y/n]' stdin
Would you like to continue?[y/n]
+ '[' '' = n ']'
+ '[' '' = N ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' y ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' Y ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' n ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' N ']'
+ printf '\nPlease use a valid input (y/n)...exiting.\n'

Please use a valid input (y/n)...exiting.
+ exit
```

---

As a healthy alternate you can just use the negative regex match on the list of allowed prompts as below

```
if [[ ! $stdin =~ ^(y|Y|n|N)$ ]]
```

---

Another efficient way to just check for just an empty string on the variable,

```
if [ "$stdin" = "" ]
```